# How do I access cPanel features within Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, server

Is there a plugin that can access cPanel features from within Wordpress? In particular I'd like to be able to:

- View bandwidth, quota and other server info from the WP Dashboard
- Access my webmail
- Access the file manager to edit files (useful for .htaccess, php.ini and non-WP files)

I know I can just open a new tab and log on to my cPanel account, but it would be great if it could be integrated some how.

If there isn't a plugin to achieve the above, then I suppose an easier way would be for some links to be added to the Dashboard menu (for example webmail and file manager) which would link directly to those sections in cPanel and perhaps open in an iframe.

So, to recap... does a plugin exist to achieve the above (or it easy to make one) or if not, does a plugin exist (or how do I create one) that adds these links to the dashboard. Any ideas from people who use cPanel and WP on a regular basis would be helpful.

Comment: I've seen such Plugins (e.g. one that brought PHPMyAdmin into the WP Admin), but I wouldn't advise using them unless you are absolutely sure about mitigating the potential security vulnerabilities involved in such functionality.

Comment: Yes, I can see the issue, especially if the cPanel username and password have to be stored for tha access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there are any plugins specifically catered to cPanel, however there are a few plugins which will allow you to add an iFrame to your admin pages.  I have not used any of these, and agree with the other commenter (Chip) who mentioned that it may pose a security risk.

With that said, check out plugins like this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/iframe-admin-pages/

search for similar: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=admin+iframe

Comment: Perhaps it might be better just to link to cPanel from within Wordpress. Then I'd have to put the username and password in, but there would be no comprimise in security.

Answer (score 0):

There is now... We've just released a brand new plugin designed specifically for accessing your cPanel web hosting account directly from within your WordPress site.

The features are a bit limited right now, but it has a lot of useful MySQL database handling - you can do action in bulk that you can't do in cPanel itself.

I'll be adding a lot more in the future and I'd be happy to hear what you'd like to see.

You can grab the WordPress plugin here:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cpanel-manager-from-worpit/

Thanks,

Paul.